# Php Mysql Create and output data with loop and conditional statement

Tags: php, mysql, sql, loops, conditional-statements

I have a php page which I'm having trouble selecting,iterating and placing the output of the selection in a multiple divs. I am running sql statements to insert the data but I can not figure out how to use php to create divs and insert the data based on the table selections. I have in one table several line_descriptions and category_ids. Each client can have any number of categories. Some may have one and others may have 20 or more. I can only do multiple select statements. I know there has to be a way to do an sql select statement with php and create a div to insert this information. It's very difficult to explain it here without a visual.

Here's a link to view the form.[https://picasaweb.google.com/lh/photo/hurjY7oAbvRoDOQQIj3zRkeSUrPF9ispRPGyalE7Lt8?feat=directlink][1].

Here's a link to the tables [https://picasaweb.google.com/lh/photo/toJ3dulOOt90avetk2u9uEeSUrPF9ispRPGyalE7Lt8?feat=directlink][2].

Here is what I want to do.

1. Select from my category_2 table category column. Insert that information into a div. Matching the category_id to the category_id and id columns from my line_item table.
2. Select from the line_item table line_description column. Insert that information into a div. Matched from the client table on client_id and id from the line_item table.

The divs that are created should be separated by category, with the item_quanity and item_unit and line_description in the next row until that category_id row has completed. Then echo the next category into another div. Attached is the php code that I've tried.
I know that I need to use some kind of loop and conditional statements but I am new to this and really trying to comprehind using loops and conditional statement and getting them to work together. I can't seem to figure out how to create a div and select one category_id and echo that into one div. Create another div if a category_id exisit and echo that out.  Any help would be appreciated.

The connect.php file

```
<?php

$config = array(    
    'host' => 'localhost',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => '',
    'dbname' => 'newest'
);  

    $db = new PDO('mysql:host=' . $config['host'] . ';dbname=' . $config['dbname'], $config['username'], $config['password']);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

?>



The select.php file

<?php
$query = "SELECT * FROM client

                JOIN job_name
                ON client.client_id = job_name.id
                JOIN estimate
                ON job_name.id = estimate.id
                JOIN line_item
                ON estimate.id = line_item.id
                JOIN category_2
                ON category_2.category_id = line_item.category_id                   
           WHERE client.email = '7895@yahoo.com'
           ORDER BY line_item.line_des_seq ASC";

// fetch gets one line
            $categorys = $db->query($query);
            $category = $categorys->fetch();           

foreach ($categorys as $lineitem){ ?>           


<?php } ?>         




    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns=http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv=Content-Type" content=text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Estimate</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estimateform.css"/>

    </head>

    <body>
    <?php
    require 'connect.php';
    require 'select.php';

    ?>

    <div id="estimateWrap">
    <div id="bodyWrap">
    <div id="header">Company Name</div>
    <div id="companyAdd">12345 Main St., Anytown USA 12345</div>
    <div id="companyPhone">Phone #: (123) 123-4567</div>

    <div id="jobType">
    <div class="estimateType">Proposal</div>
    </div>


    <div id="jobHeading">
    <div id="dateSpace">Date:</div>
    <div id="date"><?php echo $lineitem ['estimate_date']; ?></div>
    <div id ="JobnameSpace">Job Name:</div>
    <div id="clientJobName"><?php echo $lineitem ['client_job_name']; ?></div>
    <div id="siteaddressSpace">Site Address:</div>
    <div id="siteAdd"><?php echo $lineitem ['site_address']; ?></div>


    <div id="clientnameSpace">Client:</div>
    <div id="clientName"><?php echo $lineitem ['client_fname']; ?>  <?php echo $lineitem ['client_lname']; ?></div>

    <div id="jobnumberSpace">Job #:</div>
    <div id="jobNumber"><?php echo $lineitem ['job_number']; ?></div>
    <div id="clientZip"></div>
    <div id="clientZip"><?php echo $lineitem ['site_zip']; ?></div>

    </div>

    <div id="area">Area:  General</div>

    <div id="Qty">Qty</div>



    <div id="Unit">Unit</div>



    <div id="Description">Description</div>

    <!-- *********************************************************************************************************** -->
    <!-- *                                      Category                                                           * -->
    <!-- *********************************************************************************************************** -->

    <div id="category"><?php $sql = "SELECT * FROM `category_2` WHERE `category_id` = 2";
      $result = $db->query($sql);


        foreach($result as $row) {
    echo $row['category']. '<br />';

        }
      ?></div>
    <!-- *********************************************************************************************************** -->
    <!-- *                                       Quanity                                                           * -->
    <!-- *********************************************************************************************************** -->
    <div id="Qty"><?php $sql = "SELECT * FROM `line_item` WHERE `category_id` = '2' AND `job_number` = 'JOB000083'";
      $result = $db->query($sql);


      if($result !== false) {
        $cols = $result->columnCount();           

        foreach($result as $row) {
    echo $row['item_quanity']. '<br />';

        }
      }?></div>

    <!-- *********************************************************************************************************** -->
    <!-- *                                       Unit                                                      * -->
    <!-- *********************************************************************************************************** -->                                                                

    <div id="Unit"><?php $sql = "SELECT * FROM `line_item` WHERE `category_id` = '2' AND `job_number` = 'JOB000083'";
      $result = $db->query($sql);


      if($result !== false) {
        $cols = $result->columnCount();           

        foreach($result as $row) {
    echo $row['item_unit']. '<br />';

        }
      }?></div>

    <!-- *********************************************************************************************************** -->
    <!-- *                                       Description                                                       * -->
    <!-- *********************************************************************************************************** -->

    <div id="Description"><?php 

     $sql = "SELECT * FROM `line_item` WHERE `category_id` = '2' AND `id` = '7'  ORDER BY `line_des_seq` ASC";
      $result = $db->query($sql);


      if($result !== false) {
        $cols = $result->columnCount();           

        foreach($result as $row) {
    echo $row['line_description']. '<br />';

        }
      }?></div>





    <!-- *********************************************************************************************************** -->
    <!-- *                                                    Category                                             * -->
    <!-- *********************************************************************************************************** -->

    <div id="category"><?php $sql = "SELECT * FROM `category_2` WHERE `category_id` IN(6)";
      $result = $db->query($sql);


      if($result !== false) {
        $cols = $result->columnCount();           


        foreach($result as $row) {
    echo $row['category']. '<br />';

        }
      }?></div>


    <!-- *********************************************************************************************************** -->
    <!-- *                                       Quanity 2                                                         * -->
    <!-- *********************************************************************************************************** -->


    <div id="Qty"><?php $sql = "SELECT * FROM `line_item` WHERE `category_id` = '6' AND `job_number` = 'JOB000083'";
      $result = $db->query($sql);


      if($result !== false) {
        $cols = $result->columnCount();           


        foreach($result as $row) {
    echo $row['item_quanity']. '<br />';

        }
      }?></div>

    <!-- *********************************************************************************************************** -->
    <!-- *                                       Unit 2                                                            * -->
    <!-- *********************************************************************************************************** -->                                                                

    <div id="Unit"><?php $sql = "SELECT * FROM `line_item` WHERE `category_id` = '6' AND `job_number` = 'JOB000083'";
      $result = $db->query($sql);


      if($result !== false) {
        $cols = $result->columnCount();           


        foreach($result as $row) {
    echo $row['item_unit']. '<br />';

        }
      }?></div>





    <!-- *********************************************************************************************************** -->
    <!-- *                                       Description 2                                                     * -->
    <!-- *********************************************************************************************************** -->

    <div id="Description"><?php 

     $sql = "SELECT * FROM `line_item` WHERE `category_id` = '6' AND `id` = '7'  ORDER BY `line_des_seq` ASC";
      $result = $db->query($sql);


      if($result !== false) {
        $cols = $result->columnCount();           


        foreach($result as $row) {
    echo $row['line_description']. '<br />';

        }
      }?></div>


    <!-- *********************************************************************************************************** -->
    <!-- *                                                    Category3                                            * -->
    <!-- *********************************************************************************************************** -->

    <div id="category"><?php $sql = "SELECT * FROM `category_2` WHERE `category_id` IN(11)";
      $result = $db->query($sql);


      if($result !== false) {
        $cols = $result->columnCount();           

        foreach($result as $row) {
    echo $row['category']. '<br />';

        }
      }?></div>  




    <!-- *********************************************************************************************************** -->
    <!-- *                                       Quanity 3                                                         * -->
    <!-- *********************************************************************************************************** -->


    <div id="Qty"><?php $sql = "SELECT * FROM `line_item` WHERE `category_id` = '11' AND `job_number` = 'JOB000083'";
      $result = $db->query($sql);


      if($result !== false) {
        $cols = $result->columnCount();           


        foreach($result as $row) {
    echo $row['item_quanity']. '<br />';

        }
      }?></div>

    <!-- *********************************************************************************************************** -->
    <!-- *                                       Unit 3                                                        * -->
    <!-- *********************************************************************************************************** -->                                                                

    <div id="Unit"><?php $sql = "SELECT * FROM `line_item` WHERE `category_id` = '11' AND `job_number` = 'JOB000083'";
      $result = $db->query($sql);


      if($result !== false) {
        $cols = $result->columnCount();           


        foreach($result as $row) {
    echo $row['item_unit']. '<br />';

        }
      }?></div>

    <!-- *********************************************************************************************************** -->
    <!-- *                                       Description                                                       * -->
    <!-- *********************************************************************************************************** -->

    <div id="Description"><?php 

     $sql = "SELECT * FROM `line_item` WHERE `category_id` = '11' AND `id` = '7'  ORDER BY `line_des_seq` ASC";
      $result = $db->query($sql);


      if($result !== false) {
        $cols = $result->columnCount();          

        foreach($result as $row) {
    echo $row['line_description']. '<br />';

        }
      }?></div>









      <!-- *********************************************************************************************************** -->
      <!-- *                                                    Category Plumbing                                    * -->
      <!-- *********************************************************************************************************** -->

    <div id="category"><?php $sql = "SELECT * FROM `category` WHERE `category_id` IN(012)";
      $result = $db->query($sql);


      if($result !== false) {
        $cols = $result->columnCount();           

        foreach($result as $row) {
    echo $row['category']. '<br />';

        }
      }?></div>  




    <!-- *********************************************************************************************************** -->
    <!-- *                                         Quanity Plumbing                                                * -->
    <!-- *********************************************************************************************************** -->


    <div id="Qty"><?php $sql = "SELECT * FROM `line_item` WHERE `category_id` = '012' AND `job_number` = 'JOB000083'";
      $result = $db->query($sql);


      if($result !== false) {
        $cols = $result->columnCount();          


        foreach($result as $row) {
    echo $row['item_quanity']. '<br />';

        }
      }?></div>

    <!-- *********************************************************************************************************** -->
    <!-- *                                       Unit Plumbing                                                     * -->
    <!-- *********************************************************************************************************** -->                                                                

    <div id="Unit"><?php $sql = "SELECT * FROM `line_item` WHERE `category_id` = '012' AND `job_number` = 'JOB000083'";
      $result = $db->query($sql);


      if($result !== false) {
        $cols = $result->columnCount();           

        foreach($result as $row) {
    echo $row['item_unit']. '<br />';

        }
      }?></div>

    <!-- *********************************************************************************************************** -->
    <!-- *                                       Description Plumbing                                              * -->
    <!-- *********************************************************************************************************** -->

    <div id="Description"><?php 

     $sql = "SELECT * FROM `line_item` WHERE `category_id` = '12' AND `id` = '7'  ORDER BY `line_des_seq` ASC";
      $result = $db->query($sql);


      if($result !== false) {
        $cols = $result->columnCount();           

        foreach($result as $row) {
    echo $row['line_description']. '<br />';

        }
      }?></div>









        <!-- *********************************************************************************************************** -->
        <!-- *                                                    Category Electrical                                  * -->
        <!-- *********************************************************************************************************** -->

    <div id="category"><?php $sql = "SELECT * FROM `category` WHERE `category_id` IN(014)";
      $result = $db->query($sql);


      if($result !== false) {
        $cols = $result->columnCount();           

        foreach($result as $row) {
    echo $row['category']. '<br />';

        }
      }?></div>  




    <!-- *********************************************************************************************************** -->
    <!-- *                                       Quanity Electrical                                                * -->
    <!-- *********************************************************************************************************** -->


    <div id="Qty"><?php $sql = "SELECT * FROM `line_item` WHERE `category_id` = '014' AND `job_number` = 'JOB000083'";
      $result = $db->query($sql);


      if($result !== false) {
        $cols = $result->columnCount();          

        foreach($result as $row) {
    echo $row['item_quanity']. '<br />';

        }
      }?></div>

    <!-- *********************************************************************************************************** -->
    <!-- *                                       Unit Electrical                                                   * -->
    <!-- *********************************************************************************************************** -->                                                                

    <div id="Unit"><?php $sql = "SELECT * FROM `line_item` WHERE `category_id` = '014' AND `job_number` = 'JOB000083'";
      $result = $db->query($sql);


      if($result !== false) {
        $cols = $result->columnCount();           


        foreach($result as $row) {
    echo $row['item_unit']. '<br />';

        }
      }?></div>

    <!-- *********************************************************************************************************** -->
    <!-- *                                       Description Electrical                                            * -->
    <!-- *********************************************************************************************************** -->

    <div id="Description"><?php 

     $sql = "SELECT * FROM `line_item` WHERE `category_id` = '014' AND `id` = '7'  ORDER BY `line_des_seq` ASC";
      $result = $db->query($sql);


      if($result !== false) {

        foreach($result as $row) {
    echo $row['line_description']. '<br />';

        }
      }?></div>
    <div id="grandtotalUpperWrap"></div>
    <div id="grandtotalSpace"></div>
    <div id="grandtotalText">Grand Total:</div>
    <div id="grandtotalamtWrap">
    <div id="grandTotal"><?php 


    $q = $db->query("SELECT * FROM estimate 
                    JOIN client
                    ON estimate.id = client.client_id
                    JOIN job_name
                    ON job_name.id = estimate.id
                    JOIN line_item
                    ON line_item.id = job_name.id
                    JOIN category_2
                    ON category_2.category_id = line_item.category_id
                    WHERE estimate.id = client.client_id
                    ORDER BY line_item.category_id, line_item.line_des_seq");


    $line_description = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);


    ?>

    $<?=htmlspecialchars($line_description['grand_total'])?>
    <?php
      //  }
      ?>
      </div>

      </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: start all over again, now that I think I understand what you want.

## 1) Database structure

I see a few design flaws in your database, and some informations do not seem very clear either.

### Client-job relation

A client should be allowed to order different jobs from your company. Maybe "Jane Sample" will want her windows re-painted this winter and get back to you this spring to have her roof fixed. For all I know, you could even have a big client like the city hall or a college, with half a dozen jobs going on at the same time.

So the job ID should not be stored in the clients table. If it is, you will have no way to associate more than one job to a given client.
This means that to register a job for a returning customer you will need either to overwrite the previous job reference (in which case you could as well delete all traces of the job in the job and item tables, since you will lose the only meaningful way to access it), or duplicate the client (which is plain silly).

Instead, the current "job_name" table should evolve into a "job table" where you would store

- the job id as a primary key (what is called "job_number_id" in the current table)
- the customer id as a foreign key
- various other job-related data, like starting date, name, etc.

### Job ID redundency

You currently have job_number and job_number_id that seem to represent the same information.
They are duplicated in 3 tables (client, job name and line_item), which is always a bad thing and should be tolerated only if you have no other solution (which is certainly not the case here).

My advice would be to store the job_number in the job table and use job_number_id (which is the primary key of the job table) as a foreign key in other tables.

Although it is not absolutely mandatory, I would advise to use job_number_id instead of job_number as a foreign key in the line_item table (everything works better when primary/foreign keys are simple integers).

### Line ??

I will assume the table holds the detailled breakdown of all jobs, i.e. the atomic operations that are to be done to complete the jobs.
However, the various names are so vague that the semantics of this table have to be guessed.

### Category ??

As far as I get it, the category_2 table lists categories of jobs like plumbing, electricity, etc.

Looking at the name of this table, questons spring to mind:

- Is there a category_1 somewhere?
- Can jobs be labelled with something else than a record of this table?

I will assume every single job must be defined as belonging to a category, and as such has a reference to one entry of this table.

### _seq ??

I don't understand what the cat_seq and line_des_seq fields are supposed to mean.

It is obviously a kind of sorting order, but defined by what/whom? Used on which occasion? Modified by which procedures?

For the moment, I will ignore these fileds completely.

I strongly suggest you refactor your DB, since sorting should be tied to a meaningful set of data (job start / completion date for instance), not an arbitrary sort order hard-coded into the database.

## 2) A preliminary bit of philosophy

### Database accesses

As for many problems, the first step to an as painless as possible resolution is to choose the right tools for the job.

I know the SQL guys will claim their 8th marvel of a language can sort all kind of problems and brew you a nice cup of coffee besides, but experience (and an engineering degree in databases and artificial intelligence back in the late 80's) told me otherwise.

- Databases are heavy, cumbersome beasts. Using them is a grievous pain in the part of one's anatomy where the sun does not shine.
  On PHP for instance, you will have to choose between the well designed but somewhat unreliable and not so well supported PDO, or whatever jargon interface corresponding to the underlying DB engine (mysqli_, sqlite_, you name it).
- SQL is probably the most verbous, ambiguous and convoluted programming language enjoying such a widespread use on planet Earth in 2014. Does SQL injection ring a bell? I know no other language that requires outside help to prevent a 12 years old from accessing a password table from behind his web browser.
- SQL standardization is a joke. Switch from MySQL to Oracle or SQLite and you'll end up debugging and rewriting half of your queries because you unknowingly used vendor-specific extensions, or each vendor had his own interpretation of whatever subtle variant of the sacro-sanct SQL92 ISO standard (or was it SQL:2008? SQL:2011? Anyway...), or simply decided to support a subset of the infinite list of keywords and syntactical variants this marvelously rich language offers.

All this being said, the benefits of databases are obvious, and my somewhat caustic rant on SQL should not give you a false impression on my respect for the people who developped such complex and efficient pieces of software as DB engines.

Beside their obvious capacity to store reliably huge amounts of structured data, databases are extremely useful when the problem is to find a needle in a haystack, i.e. retrieving a modest amount of specific data from a huge heap of similar data.

For instance, imagine your company has been happily working for 10 years. The database will likely contain hundreds of customers and jobs, plus tens of thousands of job "lines".
Nevertheless, with a single query, you will be able to retrieve the half-dozen lines you want for a given customer (let's say "Jane Sample" and the 6 tasks necessary to refurbish her Westchester Rental office).

To extract these 6 lines, the DB engine will have to plow through megabytes of various records.
Fine, that's what it's here for, and no other piece of software could do that job better.

But it has a cost.

Now, if you *loop* on such kind of queries as this (taken from your example)

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM client

                JOIN job_name
                ON client.client_id = job_name.id
                JOIN estimate
                ON job_name.id = estimate.id
                JOIN line_item
                ON estimate.id = line_item.id
                JOIN category_2
                ON category_2.category_id = line_item.category_id                   
           WHERE client.email = '7895@yahoo.com'
           ORDER BY line_item.line_des_seq ASC";
```

you will ask the DB engine to plow through these thousands of records each time you want to pull a straw out of the haystack.
Overindulging in this kind of requests could easily multiply the DB processing time by 10 or 100.

This is a gross misuse of the DB engine. A typical example of [Schlemiel the Painter's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schlemiel_the_Painter%27s_algorithm)

At first it will seem to work, because your test db only contains a handful of data. Let it grow for a couple of years in real conditions and the thing will become increasingly sluggish.

Computers and networks are so powerful that you might very well never notice the difference, but nevertheless this is an incredible waste of CPU, memory and disk usage.

Should the slowdowns become too much of a pain, the SQL guys will come and advise you to migrate to their FasterThanLight(r) architecture with triple redundency servers, load balancing and lazy caching (all this at a bargain price, because you must remember they are your friends doing you a favor out of kindness), but nevertheless your time and your money will be wasted trying to cope with your fundamentally flawed software design.

Last but not least, if the prospect of sparing your users unnecessary delays and the planet a waste of electricity and computer hardware is not enough to make you go easy on SQL queries, I can assure you that doing the equivalent processing in PHP will result in cleaner, easier to maintain and more compact code.

To sum it up, DB queries should be limited to the retrieval of the minimal set of data required by the task at hand.
Once you've got what you need, use another tool to finish the job.

### Using associative arrays

Like many other languages (perl, python, awk, lisp, javascript and many others I never tried), PHP offers easy access to **associative arrays**.

It is a wondefully expressive tool to get data organized, but if you're not familiar with it I'm affraid you will suffer reading the rest of this post.
So, if need be, I advise you to pray the Google God to enlighten you on that matter before reading on.

## 3) Editing a work proposal

It's time to try to tackle your problem.

### Input parameters

I see you use the customer's e-mail as a candidate key for retrieving the job you want to edit.
As discussed before, this is conceptually wrong.

Suppose the customer is the city hall, with 5 different jobs going on simultaneously. Your database in its current state is unable to support that information.

What you could do, after the proper DB modifications, would be to:

- retrieve the customer's id from its e-mail address
- retrieve the list of the jobs currently open for this customer
- print a different summary for each job

For now I will simplify the problem and suppose you've got an unique job ID as the input for your job proposal edition page.

### Conventions

I will assume you have fixed the discrepancies noted above.

I will use job_number_id as the main input.

I will use syntax shortcuts:

- `$xxx` means a PHP variable
- `$xxx = select_one( ... )` means you perform the SQL query and get back the result into $xxx

I will use pseudo functions:

- `select_one` means you get the firts record that matches the select clause. For instance, when you fetch a client from the Clients table you will retrieve only one client.
- `select` means you get multiple lines from the query. For instance, there might be multiple instances of what you call "lines" associated with a given job.
- `fetch` means you get one line from a select_multiple result.

One record will be retrieved as an associative array.

For instance, `$job_data = select_one (* FROM Jobs WHERE job_number_id=1)` will assign `("client_job_name" => "Paint", "job_number" => "JOB000022", etc.)` to `$job_data`.

I will leave aside parameters sanitization, and dispense with all sorts of quoting, escaping, etc.

Finally, I assume all the pseudo-PHP code will run in the context of an object, so I consider the variables accessable from every function, as properties would be from different object methods.

### Fetching what you need from the database

```
<?php

function retrieve_proposal_data ($job)
{
    // fetch the current job's data
    $job_data = select_one ("* FROM Jobs WHERE job_number_id=$job");

    // fetch client data
    $client_id = $job_data["client_id"]; // this requires you to fix your database
    $client_data = select_one ("* FROM Client WHERE client_id=$client_id");

    // get the list of the "items" for this job
    $job_items_list = select ("* FROM Items WHERE job_number_id=$job");
    $job_item = array();
    while ($item = fetch ($job_items_list))
    {
        // add one record to the item list
        $job_item[] = $item;
    }

    // get the item category names
    $category_name = Array();
    $categories_list = select ("* FROM category_2");
    while ($category = fetch ($categories_list))
    {
        // build an index of the category names by category id
        /*
         * the "category" field of the "category_2" table should be named "name"
         */
        $category_name [$category["category_id"]] = $category["category"];
    }

    // we're done with the database. You can close the DB connection here
}

?>
```

After our short visit to Mrs DataBase, we've got:

- all client informations (name, address, phone, whatever) in the `$client_data` associative array
- all global job information (name, identifier, etc) in the `$job_data` associative array
- an unsorted list of the job items in the `$job_item` array
- a list of the job categories in the `$category_name` array, indexed by their actual DB key

### Getting data organized

Client and job informations are ready to be put inside your HTML page.
The only piece of data that needs further processing is the list of job items.

What we want is to group the job items under each category:

```
<?php
function group_job_items ()
{
    $jobs_by_category = array();
    foreach ($category_name as $category_id => $name)
    {
        foreach ($job_item as $item)
        {
            // skip job items that do not match the current category
            if ($item["category_id"] != $category_id) continue;

            if (!isset ($jobs_by_category[$name])
            {
                // create a list of jobs for the current category
                $jobs_by_category[$name] = array();
            }

            // add the current job item to the current category
            $jobs_by_category[$name][] = $item
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Now we have the `$jobs_by_category` array, indexed by job categories, that holds a list of all job items corresponding to a given category.

### At last, we get to the HTML

Putting the unique informations like client's name or job's name is a trivial matter. Just use associative arrays like you do in your existing code.

Displaying the list is a bit more complicated.

We will start with an HTML template, to visualize what PHP will have to generate:

```
// sample job category
<div class='job_category'>Rough Carpentry</div>

// sample job item
<div class='job_qty'        >1                                  </div>
<div class='job_unit'       >EA                                 </div>
<div class='job_description'>Repair exterior Hip / Common Rafter</div>
```

The div contents will have to be replaced by actual data fields.

Using CSS classes is much more appropriate than IDs, since it will allow to format each item the same way with a very simple CSS file.

Now we will look at the general page structure:

```
// company informations (sample)
<div id="estimateWrap">
<div id="bodyWrap">
<div id="header">Company Name</div>
<div id="companyAdd">12345 Main St., Anytown USA 12345</div>
<div id="companyPhone">Phone #: (123) 123-4567</div>

<div id="jobType">
<div class="estimateType">Proposal</div>
</div>

// client information (sample)
<div id="clientnameSpace">Client:</div>
<div id="clientName">
    <?php echo $client_data ['client_fname']." ".$client_data['client_lname']; ?>
</div>

// job item header
<div class='job_qty'        ><b>Qty        </b></div>
<div class='job_unit'       ><b>Unit       </b></div>
<div class='job_description'><b>Description</b></div>

// list of job items grouped by categories
<?php display_job_list(); ?>

// page footer if need be
<p>(c) 2014 kuroi-neko. Send your gifts to ...</p>
```

and at last, the PHP function that will output the list

```
<?php

// helper function to output a div of a given class with a given contents
function output_div ($class, $contents)
{
    echo "<div class='$class'>$contents</div>";
}

// the main beast
function display_job_list ()
{
    foreach ($jobs_by_category as $category_name => $job_items)
    {
        // display job category
        output_div ('job_category', $category_name);

        // browse through job items
        foreach ($job_items as $item)
        {
            // output the 3 fields of this item
            output_div ('job_qty'        , $item['item_quantity'   ]);
            output_div ('job_unit'       , $item['item_unit'       ]);
            output_div ('job_description', $item['line_description']);
        }
    }
}
?>
```

And Bob's your uncle. Or at least it should. Maybe.

Comment: The $db is my database connection. I wasn't sure to include the whole code are just some. It basically just repeats in different divs selecting different category id's. What I'm looking for is to create the div through php if there are additional category id's. Did you take a look at the form on the link? @kuroi neko

Comment: Well I did, but still it's a bit hard to piece together what you intend to do. First, the form seems rather odd, listing tons of operations with a quantity of zero. Second, the DB is complex enough, so expecting us to reverse-engineer the proper queries and produce a working SQL+PDO+PHP+HTML code might be something of a tall order. Maybe you could start with providing the SQL queries you want to be displayed, read the PHP manual as suggested to see how your DB connection is used, update your question to reflect your progresses, and we could go on from there. What do you think?

Comment: I added the connect and select php codes to the top. This codeing works but, does not create the divs by php nor is it selecting the category ids and outputting the information into separate divs.

Comment: I dont understand why this would be so difficult for an experienced php mysql programmer. I have read a few books as well as searched many web sites. For example, murach's PHP and MySQl, O'Reilly Programming PHP & PHP Cookbook. It is quite difficult to understand the concept without an actual instructor providing a more detail explaination. I am just a beginner with this I could remove some of the codeing to make reading a little easier if that would help

Comment: The form is a proposal for construction work for different clients the codeing selects the clients proposal on client email. Each client may have one or more categories with line item descriptions that match each category. I have no problem just echoing out all the categories and lineitems. What I want to do is echo out all the plumbing with the line item in one div and echo the category that matches the lineitem in another separate div for each category. Are we together on this? As my link to the form suggest.

Comment: @user3135712 See my edit. Done enough typing for today, so don't expect an immediate response.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed tutorial. Is this a working code? Because I get a Parse error on the function group_job_items. Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' on line 17. What's wrong here?

Comment: No, it's just pseudo-code that looks like PHP. Hopefully, it should be enough to get you started.

Comment: Okay, you got me on the php functions. I've never used them before. Should all of the functions be in one php file and between one php tag <?php ?> like so? Or separate files?

Comment: Thank you very much for the lesson, you've taken me into some uncovered territory creating and calling functions, use of arrays, codeing PHP apps, Databases ect... Oh and let not forget pseudo-code. As I stated I am very new at PHP, MySql, database css and html. I this thrown at me at once. You instructions and guidance was wonderful. I may have more question for you at a later time. Thank you very much.

Comment: Stop that, you're making me blush... :)